# Logic behind finding out Pascal's Triangle

Tags: java, pascals-triangle

I found a bit of code to obtain Pascal's triangle without using arrays or nCr in Java, given below:

```
int maxRows = 6;
int r, num;
for (int i = 0; i <= maxRows; i++) 
{
    num = 1;
    r = i + 1;

    //pre-spacing
    for (int j = maxRows - i; j > 0; j--) 
    {
        System.out.print(" ");
    }

    for (int col = 0; col <= i; col++) 
    {
        if (col > 0) 
        {
            num = num * (r - col) / col;
        }
        System.out.print(num + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

For the life of me I can't figure out how this bit of code generates the required number (next in the sequence) :

```
    for (int col = 0; col <= i; col++) 
    {
        if (col > 0) 
        {
            num = num * (r - col) / col;
        }
        System.out.print(num + " ");
    }
```

Could someone please explain the logic behind how the number is generated? I'm interested in understanding how the formula for the next bit of number is obtained, i.e., how `num=num*(r-col)/col` works! I'm also interested in finding out how to derive such a formula.

Comment: sounds like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem binomial coefficients

Comment: @Toumash How exactly is the binomial theorem being used here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24294192/computing-the-binomial-coefficient-in-c/24294262#24294262

Comment: At least the fraction is cut. I dont know, thats your job :P We are just giving you tips

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all a little bit of theory: 
Pascal's triangle consists of binomial coefficients, where the entry on the kth column of the nth row represents the coefficient of x^(n−k)y^k, which can be calculated using the formula (n choose k), i.e. n! / ((n - k)!k!).
More details can be found on [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Statement_of_the_theorem).

Now let's look at the code.

```
num = num * (r - col) / col
```

Say we're now computing the value of num at the nth row and kth column. Before executing this line, num has the value of nth row and (k-1)th column, i.e.

```
num == (n choose (k-1)) == n! / ((n - (k-1))!(k - 1)!)
```

and the new value of num should be:

```
    (n choose k) 
== n! / ((n - k)!k!) 
== (n! / ((n - (k-1))!(k - 1)!)) * (n - (k-1)) / k 
== num * (n - k + 1) / k
```

And so to get the new value of num (from the num representing previous entry), we need to multiply it by (row # - col # + 1) and then divide by the column #.

This is exactly what the code is doing. In this line:

```
num = num * (r - col) / col
```

r is actually == (row # + 1), and col is col #.

p.s. Don't know how to format formula on stackoverflow yet. Need to clean up my answer once I figure out how to do so.